# Why System.Decimal inheritance hierarchy

Tags: c#, resharper

I was under the impression that **all** value types inherit from [System.ValueType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx), and because I know that [Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is a **struct** which is also a value type it goes to say that Decimal hence *must be a value type*.  So why does resharper show the type hierarchy as such:

[image]

or am I misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I show (in ReSharper 5.1) *Decimal* in another view mode (*Supertypes Hierarchy*) I see that:

[image]

So all is as you would expect.

Comment: This is the answer - I had the 'Hide Library Elements' button enabled

Answer (score 6):

Decimal does not *derive* from IFormattable, it merely *implements* the IFormattable interface.

Implementing an interface is sometimes called 'inheriting', and it looks almost the same.

I'm more surprised resharper does not show the rest of the interfaces.
Go To definition (F12) in VS shows:

```
 public struct Decimal : 
       IFormattable, IComparable, IConvertible, IDeserializationCallback, 
       IComparable<decimal>, IEquatable<decimal>
```

Comment: I understand that it's not deriving as such, but my question is why is ValueType not there?

Comment: Well, I think @Jon answered that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no type that actually *inherits* from `System.ValueType` in the traditional sense of inheritance as expressed in code (there is `System.Enum`, but for the purposes of this discussion it doesn't matter). `ValueType` is a special type not intended to be used in code; you "inherit" from it by declaring that a type is a `struct`:

> Although `ValueType` is the implicit base class for value types, you
>   cannot create a class that inherits from `ValueType` directly. Instead,
>   individual compilers provide a language keyword or construct (such as
>   `struct` in C# and `Structure…End Structure` in Visual Basic) to support
>   the creation of value types.

This type of "inheritance" is handled by the compiler, which has knowledge of these "special" types (for example, there's also `System.Void`).

The inheritance hierarchy you show corresponds to the traditional concept of inheritance, so it does not reflect the relationship between `ValueType` and `Decimal` (or any other `struct`).

Comment: Boxed instances of value types do indeed inherit from `ValueType`, in the usual sense of the term.  What makes value types weird is that in most cases a storage location of type `T` means "something that can hold a reference to a heap object of type `T`", but if `T` derives from `ValueType` a storage location of type `T` means "something which can hold all of the data associated with T`.